# iPhone 4S/IOS6 - battery drain after the camera usage

Tags: iphone, battery, ios, camera

I just discovered that my iPhone4S/IOS6 battery drains too fast after I use the camera. So:

- After the fresh restart the phone lasts 3 days - when not taking photos or videos.
- Even if I take one photo (and of course, stop the camera app) the phone will drain the battery in 1 day.

The GPS (triangle icon) disappears after I stop the camera app.

I tested the above several times - enough take one photo (or short video) and the phone draining the battery in 1 day. When I restart the phone after taking photos, the phone will continue okay and lasts 3 days.

Are there any hints about this specific battery-drain problem? (I have already read the [general battery hints](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html).)

Comment: I don't even get close to a full day on my phone... and that is whether I use the camera app or not... I think part of my problem is that I don't have service at work, and barely have it at home (without going outside) So it is constantly searching for service... Of course I should put it in airplane mode at work, but then iMessage doesn't work...and I have a hard time remembering anyways...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its the GPS, do you have Photo stream turned on?  That will upload your pictures to iCloud.  One thing you can do is check usage to see what is doing on after you take pictures.  [Is my iPhone 5S draining battery too fast (and is it due to process mediaServerD?)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127205/is-my-iphone-5s-draining-battery-too-fast-and-is-it-due-to-process-mediaserverd?rq=1) has good information in the OP about checking what is using your battery.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to kill the GPS. This is because the GPS will still be on even if you don't see the triangle icon, it will still be running in the background.

The same goes for Wi-Fi/Bluetooth.

Comment: How do you kill the GPS?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off "Location Services" on your iPhone will eliminate GPS usage from draining your battery. Here's how:

1. On your iPhone, open "Settings" > Privacy > Location Services.
2. Slide the button to Off.

This will disable ALL location services (GPS). You can also turn off access for individual apps.

P.S. I  think you're getting better battery life than you realize, my iPhone 5 barely lasts a day of normal use.